binomial distribution but sometimes the last outcome doesn't matter
Here's the motivation for my question: I'm designing an RPG. To simplify as much as possible, lets say my enemy has $h = 4$ HP and I deal $a = 1$ damage with every attack.
However, there's also a $p$ chance that I can deal a critical hit $\left(\text{for the sake of the example, lets say} p = \frac{1}{3}\right)$ that deals $2 \cdot a$ damage instead.
Can I find a closed form $f_{h}(t)$ that calculates the expected probability that it will take me exactly $t$ turns to win the fight? (i.e, attacking until at least $h$ damage is dealt)
The key difference between this and just the usual binomial distribution is that the fight may end in a redundant crit and would still take the same number of turns.
So, in this example, $f_{4}(3)$ is the probability of having any of the following sequences of crits and non-critical hits:



Sequence
Expected Probability




hit, hit, crit (for a total of exactly 4 damage over 3 turns)
$(1-p)^2 \cdot p = \frac{4}{27}$


hit, crit, hit (4 damage)
$\frac{4}{27}$


hit, crit, crit (overkilled by dealing 5 damage, but it still took 3 turns)
$(1-p)\cdot p^2 = \frac{2}{27}$


crit, hit, hit (4 damage)
$\frac{4}{27}$


crit, hit, crit (5 damage)
$\frac{2}{27}$


sum of all of the above
$f_4(3) = \frac{16}{27}$



We can further calculate $f_4(4) = \frac{8}{27}$ and $f_4(2) = \frac{3}{27}$ for a total probability over all possible turn counts of 100%, as a sanity check.
But as we can see in rows 3 and 5, it doesn't quite fit the pattern of a binomial distribution because we sometimes have 2 crits in the sequence of 3 turns instead of the usual 1, because the last attack in the sequence can be either. So, how would we calculate $f_h(t)$ in general?

The problem you have is that we can overkill. So let's analyze these cases:
If a normal hit deals $1$ HP damage, and a crit $2$ HP, then the turn in which we finish the fight is either when the enemy is at $1$ HP (and it doesn't matter whether we crit or not next round), or if the enemy is at $2$ HP, and in the next round we crit.
Let's call:

$N$ the probability that we deal $h-1$ damage in $t-1$ turns
$C$ the probability that we deal $h-2$ damage in $t-1$ turns

So, the probability that we take exactly $t$ turns for the fight is:
$$
N\cdot p+N\cdot(1-p)+C\cdot p
$$
And in both $N$ and $C$ the issue of overkilling is gone. Can you take it from here?


"And in both  and  the issue of overkilling is gone."

I see! I think I gave this a brief thought but just assumed/guessed it would be recursive; but here we are asking for exact damage in exact turns, which is just the binomial coefficient now. I think I can figure it out from here!

Way 1: use renewal methods based on tracking the enemy's HP as a Markov chain. This method has the advantage that it doesn't matter how complicated the rolls for your damage might be; as long as they are independent and identically distributed, you can adapt this method to work out.
The possible states in your first example are $\{ 4,3,2,1,0 \}$. The probability to get from $4$ to $0$ in exactly $n$ steps is $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & q & p & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & q & p \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & q \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^{n-1} \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ p \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/637986/deriving-the-distribution-of-markov-chain-times for some details about where this came from.
From here you get $P(T=2)=p^2,P(T=3)=q^2 p + 2pq,P(T=4)=q^3$. That middle expression is indeed equivalent to $1-p^2-q^3$ as it should be.
In this small example, this method is overkill. That's because, to get the kill in 2 hits, you need 2 crits in a row, which has probability $p^2$. On the other extreme, to have the kill take 4 hits, you need 3 non-crits in a row followed by anything, which has probability $q^3$. The only other possibility is 3 hits.
Way 2: take advantage of the simplicity of the situation to reduce to the binomial case.
At the end, you either crit or you don't. If the enemy had 2 HP, then you needed to crit; if they had 1 HP, then you didn't need to crit. So let $D_n$ be the damage done after $n$ steps and $T$ be the number of steps to get the kill. Then $P(T=n)=p P(D_{n-1}=h-2) + P(D_{n-1}=h-1)$. But now those two probabilities are just the probability that a Bin($n-1,p$) (which models the number of crits you need) takes the value $h-n-1$ or $h-n$ (the amount of damage you need in excess of 1 per hit in each case).
